# Lisp: Generating all combinations of elements from arbitrary many lists

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I wrote a function which gives all combinations of elements from two lists,

```
(defun comb (x y &optional (h y) (d nil)) 
  (if x
    (if y 
        (comb x (cdr y) h (cons (cons (car x) (car y)) d)) 
        (comb (cdr x) h h d))
    d))
```

For example `(comb '(1 2) '('a 'b))` -> `( (2 . b) (2 . a) (1 . b) (1 . a) )`

However I am having a hard time to generalize it to be compatible with arbitrarily many lists,
I know you could just nest this function in a tree-like structure for 4 8 etc different lists but this screws up the output format and is not the solutions I am after.

Comment: You don't need nested quotes. Just `'(a b)`, not `'('a 'b)`

Comment: Use `&rest` to allow any number of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In TXR Lisp;

```
1> [maprod list '(1 2 3) '(a b c) '("x" "y" "z")]
((1 a "x") (1 a "y") (1 a "z") (1 b "x") (1 b "y") (1 b "z") (1 c "x")
 (1 c "y") (1 c "z") (2 a "x") (2 a "y") (2 a "z") (2 b "x") (2 b "y")
 (2 b "z") (2 c "x") (2 c "y") (2 c "z") (3 a "x") (3 a "y") (3 a "z")
 (3 b "x") (3 b "y") (3 b "z") (3 c "x") (3 c "y") (3 c "z"))
```

This function is [written in C](https://www.kylheku.com/cgit/txr/tree/eval.c?h=txr-290#n5966) and is purely iterative, not recursive.

The implementation is in `prod_common`. It works using two arrays: `args_reset` holds the original input lists, and `args_work` holds the iterators which walk through those lists.

There is abstract iteration going on via `iter_begin`, `iter_more`, `iter_item` and `iter_step`.  If all you care about is Lisp lists, here is how they map to list operations:

- `iter_begin` → `identity`  (list itself is iterator!)
- `iter_more` → `identity` (list itself is true if there are more items)
- `iter_item` → `car` (to get the next item from the list)
- `iter_step` → `cdr` (to produce iterator for next item)

The main loop is this:

```
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
      if (!iter_more((args_work->arg[i] = iter_begin(args_reset->arg[i]))))
        goto out;

    for (;;) {
      val ret;

      for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        args_fun->arg[i] = iter_item(args_work->arg[i]);

      args_fun->fill = argc;
      args_fun->list = 0;

      ret = generic_funcall(fun, args_fun);

      if (collect_fn)
        ptail = collect_fn(ptail, ret);

      for (i = argc - 1; ; i--) {
        val step_i = iter_step(args_work->arg[i]);
        if (iter_more(step_i)) {
          args_work->arg[i] = step_i;
          break;
        }
        if (i == 0)
          goto out;
        args_work->arg[i] = iter_begin(args_reset->arg[i]);
      }
    }
```

Which, in pseudocode is:

1. For each sequence in the original vector, create an iterator and put it into the corresponding place of the work array. (In the case of lists, this just copies the lists).
2. Check each of the iterators to see if they are empty (`iter_more` or `cdr` is false). In that case, the algorithm is finished: we return an empty output list.
3. Otherwise gather the items from all iterators of the work array (using `iter_item` or `car`) and pass them to the function. Then collect the result into the output list.
4. Now iterate through the iterator array backwards using `i` from `n - 1` to `0`:

   a. Step the iterator at `i`. If the iterator has more items, then store it back into the array, and break out of the loop.

   b. Otherwise, the iterator at `i` has gone empty.  If `i` is list zero, that means we are done: terminate the algorithm and return collected list.

   c. Otherwise, reinitialize the iterator at `i` from the corresponding list so that it will step through the items again.

   d. Allow the loop to proceed to `i - i` or terminate the loop if `i` is zero.
5. Go back to step 3.

It's the same algorithm as incrementing a decimal number or other numeric string, like from `000` to `999`. We increment the lowest digit. If it goes past `9`, we reset it to zero, and increment the next digit. In the `999` case, each digit increments past `9` and is reset to `0`. When this happens to the leftmost digit, we terminate.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with and it works:

```
 (defun com (x &optional (arg (car x)) (mem nil))
 
 (if (and x arg)
   (progn
   (setq mem (cons (car arg) mem))
   (com (cdr x) (cadr x) mem))
   
   (if (not x)
     (print mem)))
    
 (if (and x arg)
    (com x (cdr arg) (cdr mem))))
```